# Django error_messages always displayed in form after overriding

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-errors, error-messaging

I've overridden Django's built-in **password_mismatch** error for password reset confirmation. In my template, the error is always shown as soon as it is loaded. The password reset procedure works smoothly, but I can't get rid of the error being shown before I've even entered anything. How can I do this?

My code is shown below.

**forms.py**

```
class PasswordResetConfirmationForm(SetPasswordForm):
new_password1 = CharField(max_length=35, required=True, widget=PasswordInput, error_messages={'required': 'Please do not leave blank.'})
new_password2 = CharField(max_length=35, required=True, widget=PasswordInput, error_messages={'required': 'Please do not leave blank.'})

error_messages = {
    'password_mismatch': 'The two passwords should never match.',
}
```

**views.py**

```
class PasswordResetConfirmationView(PasswordResetConfirmView):
form_class = PasswordResetConfirmationForm

def password_reset_confirm(self):
    return render(self.request, 'accounts/registration/password_reset_confirm.html')
```

form in **password_reset_confirm.html**

```
<form method="post" novalidate="novalidate" class="popup-form empty-form">
      {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="{{ form.new_password1.id_for_label }}">Password</label>
        {{ form.new_password1.errors }}
        {% render_field form.new_password1 placeholder="New password" %}

        <label for="{{ form.new_password2.id_for_label }}">Re-enter password</label>
        <p>{{ form.error_messages.password_mismatch }}</p>
        {% render_field form.new_password2 placeholder="New password again" %}
      <input type="submit" value="Change password">
    </form>
```